# How to initialize a 2D array in which the size is determined by argc and argv?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on code which will keep track of each time a specific element in an array is accessed. The array itself will be allocated dynamically based off of the inputs by the user, and so no functions that I have seen are what I'm looking for. To be more specific, how do I dynamically allocate the rows and columns of an array, and then initialize every element to 0?
Ex.
./SIM A B

```
int* array_columns = malloc(atoi(argv[1]) * sizeof(int));
int* array_rows = malloc(atoi(argv[2]) * sizeof(int)); 
int array[*array_rows][*array_columns];
```

everything that I have seen requires knowing beforehand the number of elements in each row/column. Can anyone give any pointers on how to initialize this array to 0?  edit: I have added the line where I attempt to establish the array

Comment: Arrays can not be dynamic, however if you are using C99 then you can use VLA which will serve your purpose. (malloc does not give you an array, only a chunk of memory)

Comment: that was one approach that I took was to malloc the memory and then set an array such as: array[*array_rows][row_columns]. I then attempted to write a nested for-loop that would write everything to 0 but it wouldn't work when I tried it. Is there a better method?

Comment: If you compile with C99 support then ”array[row][col];” should work. And for the dimensions just do ”int col = atoi(argv[1]);” etc

Comment: establishing the array isn't necessarily the issue here, as it seems that you're suggesting that I use the technique that I am using, my issue is setting the contents to 0 when I don't have a way to verify the length of columns and rows. Do you have any tips for that?

Comment: But you get the col/rows from argv? So just iterate the array and set the values to 0.

Comment: I tried that idea and I keep getting segfaults :/

Comment: please show your code which causes the segfault when setting the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program allocates memory using command line parameters and creates a variable that can be accessed using array syntax. It uses `calloc` to initialize values to zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int **array;

    int length = atoi(argv[1]);
    int width = atoi(argv[2]);

    array = calloc(length, sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = calloc(width, sizeof(int));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            printf("array[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiled With**

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o scratch scratch.c
```

**Output**

```
[user@machine]: ./scratch 3 5
array[0][0] = 0
array[0][1] = 0
array[0][2] = 0
array[0][3] = 0
array[0][4] = 0
array[1][0] = 0
array[1][1] = 0
array[1][2] = 0
array[1][3] = 0
array[1][4] = 0
array[2][0] = 0
array[2][1] = 0
array[2][2] = 0
array[2][3] = 0
array[2][4] = 0
```

**Note**

I left out input validation and error checking to keep the example small.

**Compiler Options**

I use `-Wall -Werror` to turn on all warnings and treat them as errors. This means the compiler won't produce an executable unless all the causes of warnings are fixed. The `-o scratch` tells the compiler what to name the output file.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did everything that I wanted it to do!

Comment: Oh wait one more issue! For some reason when I implement the functions that you described everything initializes to 0 except for the first 2 rows, which have garbage values. What ideas do you have to fix this issue?

Comment: I realized that on the first calloc call I did "sizeof(int)" and not "(int*)" and so when I changed that it worked!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter 1D, 2D or ND. You can use two strategies:

The first is to create a simple 1D array as

```
int *a = (int *)malloc(atoi(argv[1]) * atoi(argv[2]) * sizeof(int));
```

The second is to create an array of arrays as below:

```
int len = atoi(argv[1]);
int len2 = atoi(argv[2]);
int **a = (int **)malloc(len * sizeof(int *));

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    a[i] = (int *)malloc(len2 * sizeof(int));
}
```

The first variant gives you a simple way to initialize and delete array, the second variant can allow to create bigger array because in this case memory chunks for child arrays can be reserved in different places of the memory.

To initialize it by some value use [`memset`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm).

**For 1D array**:

```
memset(a, 0, sizeof(int) * len * len2);
```

**For array of arrays**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    memset(a[i], 0, sizeof(int) * len2);
}
```

**P.S.** Some modern compilers allow you to initialize dynamic array as static but  that code can have troubles when you will try to compile it in another environment.
**P.P.S.** Sorry for my English, I hope someone will fix it to human-readable English.

Comment: I know it’s pedantic, but when we answer on SO we should be clear, your suggestion does not create arrays. This is one misstake which I see very often, it’s minor but still spreads missinformation.

Comment: @Fredrik, `malloc` dynamically reserves the memory for a something, in this case it's for array.

Comment: @Wax it reserves memory yes, but not for an array. What you get is an int pointer which points to some memory, and that is not an array.

Comment: Fredrik, an array is simply a collection of items stored at continuous memory locations and malloc gives you that needed memory location.

Comment: @BlooB yes the memory may look the same behind the scene, but you don have an array type, you have in this case an int pointer type.

Comment: @Fredrik, in C no arrays by so logic. The array is an abstract term for C. But I still noticed it in my previous comment. I don't think it can call some misunderstanding.

Comment: @Wax Array is not an abstract term in C, it’s a well defined type. They are different from pointers and will create different compiled code when used vs when using pointer/malloc.

Comment: so could I use memset on both the row and column malloc variables and assign the array?

Comment: @Fredrik, oh, okay. It's well defined type that exists until the compiler will finish a work. Better? But when you need to create a dynamic array you will allocate a memory chunk, not array. C hasn't syntax to it looked like you create an array. I mean a something as `int[] a = new int[size];`. So what are all these debates for? P.S. I know that some compillers let it but it's not a standard.

Comment: @Wax the debate got out of hand, the point I was trying to make was that we should not claim malloc is giving an array, only memory. As I said, it’s a little pedantic and probably not very important, so lets stop argue.

Comment: @Jenks, with 1D array you use `memset` just on that array. In the second variant you need to use it only for child array because you main array holds pointers. And sorry I missed a bit I fixed answer. check it. You need a pointer to pointer in the second way for the main array.